# When installing on a 32-bit laptop, automatic partitioning is not available

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Problem machine is a Toshiba Satellite L300, Celeron T1600@1.66GHz 32-bit, 2GB RAM, 160GB HDD with 2 partitions, (Recovery and Win7) with 90.1GB Free. As far as my limited knowledge can tell it has BIOS, not UEFI. It was originally supplied with Vista but upgraded to Win7 from a genuine upgrade pack. 
When Microsoft announced the withdrawal of support for 7, I pondered a long time before deciding to change to Linux. (I have a Win10 laptop, too, and I absolutely detest that OS, so upgrading Windows was a non-starter.) However, I still need Windows for some specific programs for my model railway hobby. So, as I'd dabbled several years ago, I went to Ubuntu, downloaded the 64-bit ISO of 18.04LTS (for my HP desktop) burned a DVD, and it installed perfectly - I basically said OK to all the defaults and it partitioned the drive, installed the OS and away we went.

I checked and found I could only use 16.04 on the laptop, so burned a DVD of that and headed to install. Now I find it will not (cannot?) perform an automatic partitioning of the HDD. All I get is the offer of wiping the drive and starting again, or doing it myself - which gives me the partition map, and a dialog giving me the option to 'Change' (the filesystem) or delete the Win7 partition. I tried using Mint instead; same problem. I found an old magazine disk with Ubuntu 15, 32-bit on it, and tried that - same issue. At my age (I'm over 70) I really don't want to go through the hassle of trying to learn GRUB and risk my Win7 partition when past experience says I shouldn't need to.

So, where is my problem - and why? And how do I resolve it?
Has my upgrade to Win7 somehow altered things? Failing that, past experience tells me that the installer should do it for me, so why am I not offered that option?
Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Usually, the auto option is not available because of the 4 primary partitions limit. It is not exactly a problem, as the user can decide which partition can be removed, and choose the last option (aka Something else). There is no need to learn Grub at any point.

Comment: @mikewhatever: That sounds a reasonable idea, but why should it apply when I only have two partitions? And choosing 'Something else' (as far as I can tell) gives me the option of deleting one or more of the existing partitions, or converting them to a different filesystem, either of which will destroy my Win7 - which I need to keep - and the recovery partition. Bear in mind that I am NOT a programmer or 'techie' - to me a computer is a tool, not a hobby - so how do I overcome the four partition limit, or, install beside Windows despite the limit?

Comment: By your own account above, there are three partitions: W7 boot, W7 system and recovery. Sometimes there is also a hidden vendor partition. There is no way for me to verify that, but you can, and also can show the result.